# Indy http post decode

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10

How can I decode & parse a URL so I can use it as POST parameters.

```
continue=http%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&service=mail&rm=false&dsh=..

var
 URL:String;
 Data:TStringList;
 MemoryStream:TMemoryStream;
begin
IdHTTP1.Post(URL, Data, MemoryStream);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it all with `TIdURI`:

- To decode use `TIdURI.URLDecode(...)`.
- To parse, pass the decoded URI to `TIdURI.Create`.

Putting it together you'd have something like this:

```
var
  URI: TIdURI;
....
URI := TIdURI.Create(TIdURI.URLDecode(EncodedURI));
try
  // Protocol = URI.Protocol
  // Username = URI.Username
  // Password = URI.Password
  // Host = URI.Host
  // Port = URI.Port
  // Path = URI.Path
  // Query = URI.Params
finally
  URI.Free;
end;
```

With acknowledgement to these answers:

- [Standard URL encode function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776302/standard-url-encode-function/776335#776335)
- [How do I parse a web URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703063)

Comment: Wouldn't this be better tho?  `URI := TIdURI.Create(TIdURI.URLDecode(URL+'/'+Params));`

Comment: Better than what? I cannot tell where your data is coming from. The tools you need are here.